# Jquery check is not behaving the way I would like to

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am creating a check with javascript/jquery, when a user fills out something it should check whether the answer is right or wrong. But whenever I try to do so it will say with each letter I fill out it's wrong untill I reach the correct answer. For instance we take the word "example". You as user should write "example", but when u are writing e-x-a-m-p-l-e it checks them as wrong untill you have written the word "example". How can I prevent such thing from happening? For it to evaluate the word after 1 or 1.5 seconds? This is my code:

```
function prepareCheck() {
$.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
   $(document).on('keyup', '.syl-input', function() {
       var rowCounter = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
       var inputCounter = $(this).attr('id');
       var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables[inputCounter];
       var jsylall = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables;
       var valueInput = $(this).val();

       console.log(jsyl);

       if (valueInput == jsyl) {
        S.addRight();
       } else if ($.inArray(valueInput, jsylall) >= -1) {
        S.addWrong();
       }
  });
});
}
```

Comment: Change the event from keyup to `change`.  Then the event will only happen when the input looses focus.

Comment: Nasty using multiple `parent().parent().parent....` . Look into using `closest()` to make code more readable and easier to debug

Comment: Also be aware that you are creating a delegate event handler inside the prepareCheck method.  If you are only calling this method once, you are fine.  However, if you are going to call this method multiple times, you are going to be creating duplicate bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code such

```
setInterval(check_answer(), 1000);
```

for starting the check

And check_answer() checks if the answer has changed since 1 second before :

- if yes, means that the user is typing, so it's useless to check the answer, we wait he's finished to type his answer
- if no (hasn't changed), means the user isn't typing anything since 1 second, then you can launch the check...

So code can be like this :

```
setInterval(check_answer(), 1000);

var old_answer="";
function check_answer() {
    new_answer = $("#answer").val();
    if ( new_answer==old_answer) {
        // nothing typed since 1 second, i launch the control and display error message if answer invalid...
    }
}
```

Another (or complementary) strategy is to say that :

- if Keydown, then the user starting typing, so we stop the setTimeout by a clearTimeout
- if KeyUp, then the user has finished typing, so we start the setTimeout...

Sample code :

```
var timer;
$field_to_check.on('keyup', function () {
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(check_answer, 1000);
 });

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$field_to_check.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```